# Does a Storm Chamber damage the user?

Tags: magic-items, iron-kingdoms

In a game of Iron Kingdoms, one of my players is an Arcane Mechanik and decided to build a mechanik device (not a Storm Glaive) using a Storm Chamber as capacitor. Will they need a StormBlade Armor?

I can find rules stating that:

- Storm Chambers "cover the user in electricity"
- When someone is "covered in electricity" they deal contact damage
- StormBlade Armor grants immunity to electricity.

I cannot find anywhere mention of being "covered in electricity" damaging the character. It seems obvious to me that it should, (and, as a consequence, that anyone using a Storm Chamber should also be using a StormBlade Armor) but I don't want to slam the GM hammer on that and tell the player he can't do it just because.

Is there a rule somewhere that explicity states a Storm Chamber wielder is damaged by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you take damage from a storm chamber

That is described under it's effects, a user handling the storm chamber without a galvanic shield take a POW 12 damage roll (2d6+12). Which is why those are used exclusively by Cygnar.

However, on top of the stormblade armor, you have another armor that can prorect you: the Stormsmith Armor (*Kings, Nations, Gods* pg. 92), for 80 gc.